# MySQL join problem

Tags: sql, mysql, join, left-join

I'm creating a simple shop, but have run into a simple problem..

I've got two tables, one called `shop` and one called `shop_orders`. `shop` has products width an `id`, `shop_orders` has a `product_id` it links back to the `shop` table and an `amount` of items in that order.

I want to filter the items in the `shop` table on best selling items, so I want to sort the `shop` table on the sum of `amount` with `shop_orders.product_id = shop.id`.

I've got the following query:

```
   SELECT shop.*, 
          SUM(shop_orders.amount) as sold 
     FROM shop
LEFT JOIN shop_orders ON (shop_orders.product_id = shop.id)
```

But it only returns all the items witch are in the shop_orders table, but I want all the items even if they aren't sold yet.

I tried using:

```
   SELECT shop.*, 
          SUM(shop_orders.amount) as sold 
     FROM shop
LEFT JOIN shop_orders ON (shop_orders.product_id = shop.id)
    WHERE shop_orders.product_id IS NULL
```

Witch returns all the items that haven't been sold yet. But if I try to use:

```
   SELECT shop.*, 
          SUM(shop_orders.amount) as sold
     FROM shop
LEFT JOIN shop_orders ON (shop_orders.product_id = shop.id)
    WHERE (shop_orders.product_id IS NULL || shop_order.product_id NOT IS NULL)
```

It returns nothing. How can I make this query work so that all the items in the `shop` table are returned with a row called `sold` witch counts this `shop_order.amount` for that `product_id` together so I can sort on that.

Comment: This is commonly modeled as Products, Orders, OrderDetails (maps between Orders and Products)

Comment: Are you missing the required `GROUP BY` clause? or did you forget to post them?

Comment: @Mitch The table is structured like that but I don't need the Orders table for this query so I left it out in my explanation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example seems like the right direction but honestly I'm a bit suprised it worked at all because as The Scrum Meister pointed out you don't have a group by clause and you have a summary function. Also if you want to order the results you'll need to add an order by clause it should look like this.

```
SELECT shop.*, SUM(shop_orders.amount) as sold
FROM shop LEFT JOIN shop_orders on (shop_orders.product_id = shop.id)
GROUP BY shop.* -- this should not be shop.* but shop.column for each column in shop    
ORDER BY SUM(shop_orders.amount) DESC
```

This should return every record in the first table shop and only records from the second table shop_orders that match a record in shop. It will also order the results based on the most ordered first. You may want to add a CASE statment or another conidtional statement to convert the NULLs in the sold column to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You seam to be missing the `GROUP BY` clause, the following query should work, returning the total amount sold, or `NULL` for products that were not sold.

```
SELECT shop.*, SUM(shop_orders.amount) as sold 
FROM shop LEFT JOIN shop_orders ON (shop_orders.product_id = shop.id)
GROUP BY shop.id
```